# Set thin font but while loading the page it showing bold and after page load it is showing thin how to resolve

Tags: css

[I want thin font while loading and after loading so please suggest me how to resolve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brBN7.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

add all your fonts locally, don't use CDN

Comment: I am using the Shopify platform and it provides an only the online solution as it cloud base platform